# How to install some ruby versions via rbenv in an isolated network environment

Tags: ruby, rbenv

#### Environment

- CentOS 6.8
- I already installed the latest rbenv on it
- Isolated from the Internet, or offline environment
- I can bring some files with `scp`

#### Question

I'd like to install some ruby versions on rbenv. But, since this server cannot connect to the Internet directly, I cannot install some ruby version with `rbenv install` command. Could you think of some ways to install some ruby versions? I don't mind whether to use ruby-build or not.

#### [Update] - What I tried so far

Created a VM with `vagrant init bento/centos-6.7`, and sent rbenv.zip and ruby-1.9.3-p286.tar.gz to its /home/vagrant/ dir.

```
yum instll -y vim zip tree gcc

sudo su -
cd /home/vagrant
unzip rbenv.zip && mv rbenv /opt/.rbenv

echo 'export PATH="/opt/.rbenv/bin:/opt/.rbenv/libexec:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile

exec $SHELL -l

mkdir /opt/.rbenv/versions

cd /root/vagrant/
tar zxvf ruby-1.9.3-p286.tar.gz && cd ruby-1.9.3-p286
./configure --prefix=/opt/.rbenv/versions/ruby-1.9.3-p286
make install

rbenv rehash
rbenv versions # -> Warning: no Ruby detected on the system
exec $SHELL -l
rbenv versions # -> Warning: no Ruby detected on the system

rbenv -v # -> rbenv 1.1.0

cd /opt/.rbenv/versions
tree -L 2 # -> The result is below
.
└── ruby-1.9.3-p286
    ├── bin
    ├── include
    ├── lib
    └── share
```

Comment: If you have an HTTP proxy available, you can set the `http_proxy` environment variable.

Comment: If you're looking to do things in a completely offline environment you probably want to use something like [Docker](http://docker.com) to prepare a VM container that's fully packaged, patched, and ready to go and can be deployed as an image. The alternative is a source install, forget `rbenv`, but that can be messy to undo.

Answer (score -1):

[*Note - This answer was posted before the last update to the original question*]

According to the [rbenv documentation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installing-ruby-versions), you should be able to compile a Ruby installation yourself, and then link it into the rbenv folder:

> #### Installing Ruby versions
>
> Alternatively to the install command, you can download and compile Ruby manually as a subdirectory of ~/.rbenv/versions/. An entry in that directory can also be a symlink to a Ruby version installed elsewhere on the filesystem. rbenv doesn't care; it will simply treat any entry in the versions/ directory as a separate Ruby version.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. I've tried a manual install too but it didn't work with some errors. I updated my questions attaching what I have done so far. It seems rbenv did not recoginize the ruby I installed manually.

Comment: Seems like a possible issue with rbenv, or something missing from the instructions. I'd open a ticket on github and ask what's going on. Please update the solution here also if you find one.

Comment: Thanks! I'll write the solution here if I find out, too :)